# Drupal Authentication with ActiveDirectory

Tags: 7, users, authentication-authorization

I'm trying to make Drupal work with ActiveDirectory just for authentication. I'm using [Lightweight Directory Access Protocol](http://drupal.org/project/ldap).

I always get this message:

> Warning: ldap_search(): Search: No such object in LdapServer->search() (line 257 of D:\wwwroot\drupal\sites\all\modules\ldap\ldap_servers\LdapServer.class.php).
>   Test sandbox-edu LDAP Server Configuration Binding with DN for non-anonymous search (testuser@sandbox.edu). Using password entered in form.
>   Successfully bound to server
>   Failed to find test user userone by searching on sAMAccountName = user one.
>   No such object

Here are the settings of the Server Properties:

```
sid = SANDBOX_EDU
name = sandbox-edu
status = 1
type = ad
address = LDAP://10.100.100.2
port = 389
tls = 0
bind_method = 1
basedn = Array
binddn = testuser@sandbox.edu
user_dn_expression = cn=%username,%basedn
user_attr = sAMAccountName
mail_attr =
ldap_to_drupal_user =
testing_drupal_username = userone
```

Can anyone who were able to get this module working with ActiveDirectory show us a sample of the setting?

If there's any other way other than using this module, please also recommend. I really need Drupal to work with ActiveDirectory for authentication because we have many students here.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following set of parameters that allow authentication by Active Directory 2003:

```
server type: "Active Directory LDAP"
server address: ad.example.com
ldap port: 389
binding method for Searches: Bind with Users Credentials
base DNs for LDAP user entries: cn=users,dc=example,dc=com
username attribute: sAMAccountName
expression for user DN: %username@company.com
email attribute: mail
```

I think the problem mainly stems from the fact that AD typically does not have the login name in the LDAP DN.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a SSO module for Drupal you could look at my answer of a previous question here:

[Automated login with LDAP always returns error](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/176568/automated-login-with-ldap-always-returns-error/221536#221536)

Or read below:

> Perhaps not a direct answer to you question about the LDAP module but
>   I managed to enable SSO in a Windows domain environment with the
>   Webserver authentication
>   (https://www.drupal.org/project/webserver_auth) module.
>
> You need to force Windows Authentication in your IIS site and disable
>   Anonymous authentication. The Webserver authentication module is also
>   capable of creating accounts when a Windows Domain user is visiting
>   your site and is not registered in Drupal.